# Multiple unexpected errors

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm not entirely sure what is wrong with these line, I don't understand why they are problematic. In the order of the problems (failing line will be highlighted with ***)

File "C:\Users\Harry\Desktop\CS Project\game test", line 32, in drawArena
    pygame.draw.line(DISPLAYSURF, WHITE, ((WINDOWWIDTH/2),0),((WINDOWWIDTH/2),WINDOWHEIGHT), (LINETHICKNESS/4))
TypeError: integer argument expected, got float

File "C:\Users\Harry\Desktop\CS Project\game test", line 144, in main
    drawArena()

File "C:\Users\Harry\Desktop\CS Project\game test", line 178, in 
    main()

```
def drawArena():
    DISPLAYSURF.fill((0,0,0))
    #Draw outline of arena
    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, WHITE, ((0,0),(WINDOWWIDTH,WINDOWHEIGHT)), LINETHICKNESS*2)
    #Draw centre line
    ***pygame.draw.line(DISPLAYSURF, WHITE, ((WINDOWWIDTH/2),0),((WINDOWWIDTH/2),WINDOWHEIGHT), (LINETHICKNESS/4))***

***drawArena()***
drawPaddle(paddle1)
drawPaddle(paddle2)
drawBall(ball)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ***main()***
```

Comment: as the error indicates, your function expects integers and you're passing it floats -- i'd look at wrapping those `/2` calls like `int(VARNAME/2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's telling you the error. When using the method `pygame.draw.line()`, you must provide integer arguments for the dimensions of the line. If you look at your problematic line:

`pygame.draw.line(DISPLAYSURF, WHITE, ((WINDOWWIDTH/2),0),((WINDOWWIDTH/2),WINDOWHEIGHT), (LINETHICKNESS/4))`

One or more of the quotients of those division operations are resulting in a float(decimal) number. One simple way to fix this is to use the Python `int()` function to round any of your decimals to a whole number, like so:

`pygame.draw.line(int((WINDOWWIDTH/2)),0),(int((WINDOWWIDTH/2)),WINDOWHEIGHT), int((LINETHICKNESS/4)))`

If int, for some reason is not suitable, you can also use the Python `round()` function:

`pygame.draw.line(round((WINDOWWIDTH/2)),0),(round((WINDOWWIDTH/2)),WINDOWHEIGHT), round((LINETHICKNESS/4)))`

Comment: There's a new error: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'

Comment: @HarryEastell My bad. I gave the wrong syntax. I'll fix it.